# Jquery - Handling a login response from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

Simply, users can login on my website.

```
$('#login').click(function() {
    var user = $('#username').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "authorize.php",
        data: { username: user, password: pass },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#data').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The ajax `success:` will fire regardless of the login working or not, right? It does no server-side processing. How do I communicate to the Jquery script from `authorize.php` that the users login has failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your php do this:

```
// your authentication magic here
if($user->authenticated) {
    $return = array('status' => 'loggedIn');
} else {
    $return = array('status' => 'failed');
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Then in your ajax call add the setting: `dataType: 'json'`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "authorize.php",
    data: { username: user, password: pass },
    dataType: 'json', // NOTE this line
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.status); // says 'loggedIn' or 'failed'
    }
});
```

Comment: My javascript breaks when I add the line `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: hmm... just tried it out, works perfectly. Can you check what response you get? (look into the 'network' tab of chrome dev. tools, or just surf to authorize.php)

Comment: It appears the problem was I had some raw HTML on the page as well. Removing this code solved the problem. Looks like I have to re-structure my pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your return data should have some kind of success or failure item within it. For example if you were using JSON, the data may be { "loginResponse" : "failed" } or similar. The success event merely states that your ajax call managed to execute and receive a response that wasn't an HTTP error. Don't confuse that with program flow.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
success: function(data) {
```

data has the text echoed out from the server.